# Chat Program Closes Automatically

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I've been attempting to learn some android development and I've been trying to get into some sort of networking so that an app I make could be web-based.  Anyways, I started by trying to make a chat program which uses a the phone or a laptop as a client, and running the server on my laptop.  My problem is that whenever I attempt to send a message to the server, my app just closes.  I'm thinking of possibilities but I'm not sure what's actually going on.

Anyways here's the android code:

```
package com.example.android.chatprogram;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage()
    {
        try {

            TextView inp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_box);
            TextView receive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat_window);
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9002); //99.228.211.122
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String msg = inp.getText().toString();
            outToServer.writeBytes(msg + '\n');
            receive.append(inFromServer.readLine());
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Here's the server code (Which runs on my laptop):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9001);

        while(true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I have found the stack trace finally!

```
05-0121:48:04.74828076-28076/com.example.android.chatprogramE/AndroidRuntime:
FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process:com.example.android.chatprogram,PID:28076
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Couldnotexecutemethodforandroid:onClick
atandroid.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
atandroid.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
Causedby:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
atandroid.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
atandroid.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
Causedby:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
atandroid.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
atjava.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
atjava.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
atjava.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:535)
atjava.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
atjava.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
atcom.example.android.chatprogram.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:29)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod) 
atandroid.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
atandroid.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: `my app just closes` what do you mean? if it crashes then add your error log!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to actually get the error log.  Whenever I use an app like LogCat, I just get a huge wall of never ending text. @AtefHares

Comment: That will be too much to explain here, I am afraid (and I guess it's better for you) you have to search google for how to deal with logcat. I am almost sure you will find lots of tutorials and videos for that.

Answer (score 0):

First-  when you have a crash, always post the stack trace.  It tells you what's failing, why, and where.

In this case, its going to be a NetworkOnMainThreadException.  All network calls must be done on another thread.